# Connect drupal site to moodle site

Tags: drupal, moodle

I am using **drupal 7.27 version** in which I need to connect to moodle site and its database. So I used drupal module moodle_connection to connect it withmoodle site. As it does not offer any end feature functionality. I installed another module called moodle_views but unfortunately there is no data received from the moodle. When I debug I found that connection does not establish between both the sites.

I am calling moodle_connector_connect() function in custom module to connect to Moodle. But no success. And in the moodle connector settings I put the following information:

```
Database Type : mysql

Database Server : localhost 

Database TCP Port : 3306

Database Name : drupal_moodle ('Name of the moodle database')

Database Prefix : mdl_

Database User : root

Database Password : (I don't have password for my database user so I kept blank)

Moodle URL : drupal_moodle (Moodle site url)
```

Please help me to get out of this.

Regards

Neha

Answer (score 0):

Reading over the bug reports in the Drupal module moodle_connector, I noticed some issues related to  setting values for the moodle database connection variables, and some issues with handling error conditions.

Combine this with your mention of blank password, suggests the following line might be a problem.

Reading moodle_connector.module, around line 51 I notice some lazy checking for unset parameters.

```
 // Return false if settings are incomplete.
 if (!$type || !$server || !$port || !$username || !$password || !$database) {
    return FALSE;
 }
```

It looks like the check for !$password will cause the function moodle_connector_connect() to exit and not connect to the moodle database if any of the values are unset or empty.

As a workaround, and a step in right direction security-wise, could you create a new MySQL user, specifically grant it the necessary privileges to allow Drupal to read the Moodle DB and set a password.

I would also strongly advise that you read over the MySQL 'post installation' section of the manual which advises setting a password on the root user accounts.   Having no root password is convenient during initial installation, but is a security problem.  Any ordinary user on the machine, or a nearby machine which can connect to port 3306, could gain full access to the database.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/postinstallation.html